# special characters in json object array

Tags: android, character, encode

I am pulling sms messages from the sms content provider in android. saving the body of a message to a string which will include special characters. saving the string to an array and sending them via json to a php script which parses using foreach to a database.  If I remove all characters except for 0-9 a-z A_Z it works fine.  If I dont remove special characters I get a PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach().  How do I remove special characters but keep ones like :, ",?

Comment: There is something wrong with your code if you have to remove special characters to make it work. It is better to fix that problem than to implement a workaround. Can you show us your code?

Comment: Hi Henry, I figured out that its the apostrophe in the text that is causing the hang up. If I dont remove it any of the strings I send that have an apostrophe will get dropped.  If I string.replaceAll("\'", "") it works fine but now I have messages missing apostrophes.  punctuation is the key here.  Any ideas as to how I can include the apostrophes?

Comment: Ok I solved it myself!  SQl didnt like the single '.  In order to insert an ' in the text like for O'Brien I had to double up and put O''Brien.  Thanks to anyone who saw this post, replied to this post or was working on a way to solve this issue!  :)